# Singleton Class in Laravel 5

Tags: php, singleton, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel Framework version 5.2.32. I wish to create a Singleton class whose object is accessible accross all controllers. I've implemented the class as below.

```
class SingletonClazz {

    private static $instance;

    protected function __construct() {
        //Do nothing
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (empty(SingletonClazz::$instance)) {
            SingletonClazz::$instance = new SingletonClazz();
            echo 'Created';
        }
        else {
            echo ', Already created';
        }

        return SingletonClazz::$instance;
    }
}
```

I'm creating an object of the class as below

```
class MyController extends Controller {

    public function initSingleton() {
        SingletonClazz::getInstance();
        SingletonClazz::getInstance();
        SingletonClazz::getInstance();
    }
}
```

The route.php file is configured as below

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'singleton'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'MyController@initSingleton'
    ]);
});
```

When I invoke the URL http://localhost:8080/singleton/initSingleton the result is **'Created, Already created, Already created'**. When I invoke the URL again, the result is the same whereas I expect it to be **'Already created, Already created, Already created'**

Can you guide on the problems with this implementation.

Comment: Unless you're writing this script to be used in a long lived (daemon-like) process, then each request to your application will be completely separate because that's how HTTP was designed. Singletons, when making web requests, will only live through a _single_ request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each request send to the PHP server, it is handled as a blank sheet so it is initializing Lavarel from the beginning. Variables defined in the previous request are not automatically saved to the next one.

It is how PHP is designed, build on top of the HTTP protocol that is also designed this way.

What you can do is store the object in a session:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['instance'])){
    $singleton = $_SESSION['instance'];
  } else {
    $singleton = SingletonClazz::getInstance();
    $_SESSION['instance'] = SingletonClazz::$instance;
  }

?>
```

But then again **why** would you want that and if so, I ***really*** suggest changing your implementation.
A singleton is structure code, where you have multiple classes with a similar interface, useless data should not be stored into sessions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. I'll look for some other elegant way of implementing it. May be Laravel Service Container as suggested by others.

Comment: I read this and can't help pointing that while being architecturally wrong (as you warned), it's also not solving ops problems. The session is only valid for a specific client, so it will not work accross different clients consuming the service.

Answer (score 1):

Why you didn't use [Laravel IoC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding) for implementing singleton?
Jeff Lambert in comments are totally right.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. I'll look at Laravel Service Container